# Error installing Android Studio! How to uninstall it completely?

Tags: 14.04, uninstall, android, android-studio

I tried installing android studio in my Ubuntu 14.04 using terminal. I entered the commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:paolorotolo/android-studio
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install android-studio
```

It was downloaded successfully but when it was getting installed, an error occurred in dconf-ing a package. It also has created an `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications` but I cannot run it. I want to uninstall it, as it was not fully installed, I tried `sudo apt-get autoremove` but didn't work.

Please help me uninstalling android studio fully.

Answer (score 1):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove android-studio
```